# android :app:processDebugGoogleServices

Tags: android

I am getting this error, I dont remember how, but I guess after I made a series of updates to versions as below:

```
Android Studio 1.5 beta
Build tools 23.0.2
Support libraries 23.1.0
```

**My gradle.build (app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hsoni.corpchat"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.3'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-bosh:4.1.3'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.3'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.3'
    compile 'org.jxmpp:jxmpp-jid:0.5.0-alpha6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/volley-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile project(':emoji')
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.2.0'
    compile project(':aFileChooser')
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:aFileChooser:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:compileLint
:aFileChooser:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:checkReleaseManifest
:aFileChooser:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:prepareReleaseDependencies
:aFileChooser:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:aFileChooser:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:compileLint
:emoji:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:checkReleaseManifest
:emoji:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:prepareReleaseDependencies
:emoji:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:emoji:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCocoswBottomsheet120Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubClansFab160Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubJohnkilAndroidRobototextviewRobototextview240Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareCorpChatAFileChooserUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareCorpChatEmojiUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0, but version 8.1.0 is needed
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0, but version 8.1.0 is needed
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0, but version 8.1.0 is needed
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0, but version 8.1.0 is needed
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0, but version 8.1.0 is needed
:app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.226 secs
Information:1 error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set in main gradle file :

```
 dependencies {

    ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this type of error many time when I was working in Firebase authentication, finally I solved and when I was searching I got your post first, so I just wanna post my solution even if you solved it before because other might see your post first.

Here, tou can see error which I got:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the 
google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at 
https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) 
or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.
```

Here is the build.gradle (app level)

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "idoston.com.firebaseauthenticationandroid"
     minSdkVersion 17
     targetSdkVersion 26
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner 
     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
      release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
  core:3.0.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
     compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
  }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Solution is that : you need to delete which is in the last line:

```
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I hope this answer will probably help someone in the future.